# Pass PHP variables to Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I've implemented a custom Google Maps script as a Wordpress shortcode but I have a problem with some of the values that are defined in the `.js` file but generated by Wordpress through PHP

This is the `.js` file:

```
//set your google maps parameters
var latitude = 41.03328,
    longitude = 21.30281,
    map_zoom = 16;

//google map custom marker icon - .png fallback for IE11
var is_internetExplorer11= navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('trident') > -1;
var marker_url = ( is_internetExplorer11 ) ? 'img/cd-icon-location.png' : 'img/cd-icon-location.svg';

//define the basic color of your map, plus a value for saturation and brightness
var main_color = '#00e1ff',
    saturation_value= -20,
    brightness_value= 5;
```

What I need to do is get the Wordpress theme directory for the images on line:

```
'img/cd-icon-location.png' : 'img/cd-icon-location.svg'
```

and for `var main_color = '#00e1ff'`,  get this value from PHP

```
<?php echo oneengine_option( 'main_color' ); ?>
```

Comment: You can read the color value from the page element or CSS rule.

Answer (score 2):

What I usually do to get JS values using PHP is declaring them before importing the JS script or the written code

```
<?php
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">var main_color = "'.$main_color.'";</script>';
?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="someJSScript.js">
    //If not in separate file, JS code will go here
</script>
```

Comment: You should include it in right place and read the variable after whole page is loaded, else you may have problems with undefined variable.

Comment: Everything I try returns either Uncaught ReferenceError: $templateDir is not defined or Var undetected. I'm pulling my hair out I hate this curly macaroni language mess that is js

Answer (score 0):

Echo the PHP variables you need into Javascript variables inside of your theme files and reference the JS variables inside of your script files.

Theme files:

```
<script>
    var config_theme_directory = "<?=get_template_directory()?>";
</script>
```

Included JS file:

```
console.log( config_theme_directory );
```